# Terminology for matrix whose inverse is itself except that off-diagonal elements are negative?

Tags: matrices, terminology, inverse

Obviously, planar rotation matrices satisfy this requirement since they can be parameterized as $$\pmatrix{{\cos(\theta) \ \  \  \sin(\theta)}\\{-\sin(\theta) \ \ \cos(\theta)}}$$

However, "hyperbolic rotation" matrices also satisfy this requirement since $$\pmatrix{\cosh(\theta) \ \sinh(\theta) \\ \sinh(\theta) \ \cosh(\theta)}\pmatrix{\cosh(\theta) \ -\sinh(\theta) \\ -\sinh(\theta) \ \cosh(\theta)}=1$$

**Are there more matrices in this class? Does this sort of matrix have a name?**

Comment: Are you just interested in the $2 \times 2$ case? It's relatively easy to tackle, but I don't know about $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: @pjs36 Sure, I know that 2x2 matrices must take the form $\pmatrix{a \ b \\ c \ a}$ where $a=\sqrt{1+bc}$. I guess I'm mostly curious about whether or not there is an easier way to describe and talk about matrices of this form or if they have any known applications or symmetries. EDIT: There are also other matrix templates that work, but the one I listed seems to be the most interesting.

Comment: Ah, I see. Given that it includes things like $\pmatrix{-5 & 12 \\ 2 & -5}$ I'd be surprised if they *all* have geometric significance, but I wasn't aware of the hyperbolic rotations, so perhaps I'm not qualified to judge :)

Comment: Let $A=D+F$, where $D$ and $F$ contain the diagonal and off-diagonal entries of $A$ respectively. Then $(D+F)(D-F)=I=(D-F)(D+F)$. From this it turns out that $DF=FD$, and $D^2-F^2=I$. Not sure where to go from there.

Comment: @Rahul good point. From here I think we can reach some other interesting conclusions, by example that $F^2$ is a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Some digging about this question:**

In general, by example from $A:=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $B:=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, we can see that these matrices doesn't form a group under matrix multiplication or matrix addition. I don't know if these matrices have a name (probably not because they are not a group under matrix multiplication or matrix addition) but the condition for $n\times n$ matrices can be stated as

$$A(2D-A)=2AD-A^2=I\tag1$$

for $D$ the matrix that is the diagonal of $A$. And because $A$ is invertible then from $(1)$ we have that

$$2D=A+A^{-1}\implies AD=DA\implies a_{k,k}a_{j,k}=a_{j,j}a_{j,k},\quad\forall j,k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}\tag2$$

Then we can see two cases from here:

1. **$A$ is a diagonal matrix:** if $A$ is diagonal then $D=A$ so the equation on $(1)$ reduces to $D^2=I$, what is easy to handle and analyze.
2. **$A$ is not a diagonal matrix:** then there is some $a_{j,k}\neq 0$ for $j\neq k$, then from $(2)$ this implies that $a_{j,j}=a_{k,k}$. Some special cases easier to handle are the following:

   2.1. **Simple non-zero diagonal:** if there is a $a_{j,j}\neq 0$ for some $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and a collection of $n-1$ coefficients $a_{j,k}\neq 0$ such that the pairs $(j,k)$ defines a connected graph on $n$ vertices then $D=\lambda I$ for some $\lambda\neq 0$. **Proof:** the idea is that there is a connected graph of coefficients that forces the condition stated in $(2)$ for all $a_{k,k}$. By example the above condition is fulfilled when $A$ have some file or column with non-zero coefficients.

   2.2 **Zero diagonal:** if $D=0$ then $(1)$ simplifies to $A^2=-I$, what is equivalent to say that $A^{-1}=-A$, what is easier to handle and analyze.

---

**All what follows from here is for the case 2.1.** From $(1)$ we find these characterizations for this subset of matrices

$$A^2+I=\eta A\quad\text{ or }\quad (A+ I)^2=\mu A\tag3$$

where $\eta:=2\lambda$ and $\mu:=2(1+\lambda)$. Also from $(3)$ we find that $$p(x):=x^2-2\lambda x+1=(x-\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda^2-1})(x-\lambda+\sqrt{\lambda^2-1})\tag4$$ is a multiple of the [minimal polynomial of $A$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) because $p(A)=0$.

Then we also knows that $A$ have at most two distinct eigenvalues (that are not zero any of them, otherwise $A$ cannot be invertible). Also by the trace of $A$ we knows that

- if $A$ have only one eigenvalue then it multiplicity is obviously $n$ and it value is $\lambda$ because $\operatorname{trace}(A)=\lambda n$. In this case, from $(4)$, we find that $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=-1$.
- if $A$ have two distinct eigenvalues then $$\operatorname{trace}(A)=\lambda n=(n-k)r_1+kr_2$$ for the eigenvalues $r_1$ and $r_2$, and for some $k\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$, where from $(4)$ it can be seen that $r_1=\lambda+\sqrt{\lambda^2-1}$, $r_2=\lambda-\sqrt{\lambda^2-1}$ and $r_1\cdot r_2=1$, so $r_1=r_2^{-1}$.

  Putting all together we find that $$\operatorname{trace}(A)=\lambda n=\lambda n+n\sqrt{\lambda^2-1}-2k\sqrt{\lambda^2-1}\implies n=2k$$
  what imply that the two eigenvalues $r_1$ and $r_2$ have the same multiplicity, and consequently $\det(A)=r_1^k\cdot r_2^k=1$. Also from here we reach the conclusion that if $n$ is odd then necessarily $A$ have only one eigenvalue because $n/2\notin\Bbb N$.

  Also if $\lambda\in(-1,1)\setminus\{0\}$ then we find that $r_1=\overline{r_2}$ and consequently $r_k\overline{r_k}=|r_k|^2=1$ so $r_1,r_2\in\Bbb S^1$.

  Also we can see from $(4)$ that, in any case, at least one eigenvalue can be chosen freely from $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I'm going to look over this material more closely, but fom a first blush, it all looks correct. I appreciate the work you put in for this.